# JavaScript url being stripped out of html

Tags: javascript, security, google-tag-manager

I have a very odd issue happening that I have been struggling with and can't find answer to.  We have a 3rd party module to add GTM to the site and after doing a deploy the GTM is fine.  After a period of time sometimes a few minutes and sometimes an hour or more the url for the JavaScript gets stripped out of the html but the GTM snippet is still there but just no url for the GTM JavaScript file. This is what I mean, this is what it starts out as.

```
<script>
    requirejs([], function() {
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','xxx-xxxxxxx');});
</script>
```

This is what is in the html after the url gets stripped out.

```
<script>
    requirejs([], function() {
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    '';f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','xxx-xxxxxxx');});
</script>
```

I am running Magento Community 2.3.6.  I have tried disabling the Magento_Csp module.  I have added the googletagmanager.com domain to the allowed list.  I have the Mage Plaza Security Pro module and have tried disabling it. Nothing seems to make a difference.  I have tried disabling the GTM module and putting the GTM snippet in the html head and the same thing happens.

I have been working with the hosting provider support and they have not been able to come up with anything either.

Anyone have any ideas at all?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from this information alone. You should debug the "3rd party module" that adds GTM code to your site.

Comment: But even when I add the GTM snippet to the html head in the admin the url is still being stripped out.

Comment: First determine if your server strips the url when rendering. If not, use the devtools JavaScript debugger to determine where the url is being removed.

Comment: Hosting provider says they have nothing in place that would do something like that.  When I use 'View Page Source" a the browser that is going to show what the server returns right ? It shows the html before any JavaScript has modified it right? When I do "View Page Source" the url is stripped out.

Comment: You still need to deduce where the transformation happens. Browser extension, proxy/cdn/waf, server? What your provider says is secondary info, you should verify that yourself.

Comment: I completely agree with all of that, the problem is that I am unable to replicate it happening.  It seems to happen on a completely random basis.

Comment: hi @TrevorOrr I have seen the same issue that you reported in a Magento 2.4.4 with the Weltpixel module (this is the one that adds the tag manager snippet for us). Curious thing is that when bypassing the Varnish full page cache I see the snippet working properly, which means (in my mind) that Magento/Weltpixel is removing the URL randomly (so Varnish caches the faulty version only some times) or that Varnish itself might be involved in the issue (but I cannot image how).

Answer (score 0):

In our case, this unexpected stripping was caused by the Amasty GDPR module, that (roughly put) decides during the execution of `vendor/amasty/gdpr-cookie/Plugin/ProcessPageResult.php` that if under some conditions (related to the _ga cookie not being in an "accepted" cookie group) it must strip away the google tag manager url and replace it with an empty string.

This is the regex expression that uses:

```
public const GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_REG = '/\'https:\/\/www\.googletagmanager\.com\/gtm\.js\?id=.*?;/is';
```

Here is where the replacement takes place (line 96):

```
if (preg_match(self::GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_REG, $output, $match)) {
    $output = preg_replace(self::GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_REG, "'';", $output);
    $response->setBody($output);
}
```

A simple workaround (if you want to load tag manager for any user in all cases, which might not be GDPR compliant...) is to modify the tag manager snippet to make the regex fail to match, for example by adding an additional/trivial concatenation to the url:

```
j.src='h'+'ttps://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
```

Although, you might want figure out under which exact conditions Amasty is running the replacement and try playing with the module cookies config instead (in a GDPR compliant way, if needed).

AFAIK the reason why a user with (for example) all cookie groups accepted might have tag manager disabled in some pages (!!!) is due to the fact that Amasty is modifying the html under certain conditions (but not touching the X-Magento-Vary cookie accordingly), which causes the full page cache system (e.g. Varnish) to serve cached versions of pages generated with some cookie preferences to users with other cookie preferences. A quick workaround for this is to add the relevant Amasty cookie value `amcookie_allowed` to the Varnish vcl hash subroutine (fortunately that cookie has a limited number of possible values, proportionally to how many cookie groups you have configured).